# Is String to Integer conversion fast or viceversa

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, string-comparison

I am in a position to compare a string with an integer in my application. So I have a choice of either converting my variable of string type to integer or vice-versa and then compare. In this case I would like to know which process is faster, is converting a string to integer or integer to string or can I use "==" and compare them.

Comment: I think String to Integer conversion is good ... then you can use '==' operator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **think** integer to string conversion is faster because every integer can be converted to a string, but the reverse conversion is not always possible, i.e. not every string represents a number.

`==` performs automatic conversion of its operands and then performs comparison, so you can use it with two operands of any type.

In the case of string and number, `==` first tries to convert the string into a number and then performs the comparison, perhaps and I am assuming this, it tries to convert the string to a number because if that fails no need for comparison altogether.

**EDIT:** I have run a few tests using `parseInt()` for string to integer conversion, and using `toString()` for integer to string conversion.

Each test was run `1000000` times, the string to integer conversion took about `3` seconds in average, the integer to string conversion took about `2.5` seconds in average.

This is not a huge difference for `1000000` operations, so unless you have a huge number of conversions to do, it won't make any difference.

Comment: Great explanation. I will for now use Integer to string conversion unless some one comes with different suggestions. Thanks for sharing the metrics too.

Comment: @Ajax3.14 Thank you, you are welcome. If you felt his answers your question, please accept when you can. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not a strictly typed language. Any `var` can be a `string`, `int`, `double`, `bool` etc.

There shouldn't be any speed difference for comparisons of two `vars`.

You can open statistic in browsers in their developer tools to see the speed of loading objects such as scripts and test for yourself if there are any differences in speed.

In Chrome, it is the `Network` tab.

Comment: what I looking here is not for a one time conversion I am checking the value against a huge collection. SO I wanted to know is there even a subtle difference both in time and space. I am also curious to know any utility function line underscore.js or something that can do this comparison in a efficient way out of the box